# How to understand the function of d_hash()?

Tags: c, filesystems, kernel

the codes is:

```
static inline struct list_head * d_hash(struct dentry *parent, unsigned long hash)
{
      hash += (unsigned long)parent / L1_CACHE_BYTES;
      hash = hash^(hash>>D_HASHBITS)^(hash>>D_HASHBITS*2);
      return dentry_hashtable + (hash & D_HASHMASK);
}
```

How to understand this function?
Particularly，the lines of "`hash = hash^(hash>>D_HASHBITS)^(hash>>D_HASHBITS*2);`"

Thank you

PS:the codes form:http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/fs/dcache.c?v=2.6.16#L885

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: @ugoren what's meaning of "hash = hash^(hash>>D_HASHBITS)^(hash>>D_HASHBITS*2);"?

Comment: @ugoren And how to understand of "hash += (unsigned long)parent / L1_CACHE_BYTES;" ?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to understand hash functions and why they are used. Next you need to know what the dcache (directory cache) is supposed to do. From [usenix.org](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix01/full_papers/kroeger/kroeger_html/node8.html): The d-cache "keeps in memory a tree that represents ... the file system's directory structure." The base element is called a d-entry

The function returns a pointer to a list, and requires a parent dentry and a hash. The list pointer is to a "bucket" ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)) of entries that have the same hash as the one provided (this will have to be search separately).

The lines you mention in the comments rely on bitwise operators ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)). '^' is exclusive or, '>>' is a right shift, '&' is a bitwise and.

That should get you started on understanding the function. You'll have to look up the constants such as "D_HASHBITS".

Comment: I have learned the filesystem of d-entry.And I don't understand the codes of " hash = hash^(hash>>D_HASHBITS)^(hash>>D_HASHBITS*2);"

Comment: What part of that line? The value in "hash" is truncated to a length of D_HASHBITS (since the right bit shift will fill with 0's to the left, which are then XORed with "hash"). This is then XORed with "hash" shifted to the right by D_HASHBITS - 1 places (since * 2 is similar to are left shift by 1).

If you don't understand it, try copying it into a simple C program to test it with different inputs.

Comment: hi the codes "hash^(hash>>D_HASHBITS)^(hash>>D_HASHBITS*2)" is a simplified CRC algorithm

Comment: Hash functions are often used for error checking, so it is not surprising that there are similarities between the two. Is there anything else you need to be able to understand the d_hash function, or is my answer acceptable?